# Magento2 Registration Form is not showing State Dropdown

Tags: magento2, forms, customer-registration

I want to show Address fields in Registration form of **Magento 2.4.0**

I have created file in my theme as below.

```
app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_create.xml
```

I have set the action method called setShowAddressFields like true by adding below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
            <action method="setShowAddressFields">
                <argument name="show.address.fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I can see address fields after adding this in the layout file, but I could not see state drop-down.
I have attached a screenshot of registration form.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create a copy of

```
/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml
```

on your template:

```
/app/design/frontend/<vendor_name>/<template_name>/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml
```

And replace lines 338-340

```
"regionJson": {$regionJson},
"defaultRegion": "{$regionId}",
"countriesWithOptionalZip": {$countriesWithOptionalZip}
```

with these

```
"regionJson": <?= /* @noEscape */ $regionJson ?>,
"defaultRegion": "<?= /* @noEscape */ $regionId ?>",
"countriesWithOptionalZip": <?= /* @noEscape */ $countriesWithOptionalZip ?>
```

flush cache.

Answer (score 1):

The state dropdown looks broken in register.phtml. Create a module, or override it in your theme.

Line 328, change it to echo the variables:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "#country": {
        "regionUpdater": {
            "optionalRegionAllowed": <?= /* @noEscape */ $displayAll ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
            "regionListId": "#region_id",
            "regionInputId": "#region",
            "postcodeId": "#zip",
            "form": "#form-validate",
            "regionJson": <?= $regionJson ?>,
            "defaultRegion": <?= $regionId ?>,
            "countriesWithOptionalZip": <?= $countriesWithOptionalZip ?>
        }
    }
}
```